# How to fire an application event inside a Promise - Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, promises

I am migrating some code from callback to promise, and in the original code we are firing an application event but this is causing the promise to enter in the catch part.

Original Code

```
somefunction : function(component){
   var action = component.get('c.someApexMethod');
   action.setParams({params});
   action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
   var state = response.getState();
    if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
    $A.get('e.c:someApplicationEvent').setParams({
        value: true
      }).fire();
    ...
    other code
    ...
    }
   });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

using Promises

```
somefunction : function(component){
   this.apex(component, "someApexMethod", {params})
   .then(function (response) {
      $A.get('e.c:someApplicationEvent').setParams({
        value: true
      }).fire();
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
},
```

When the Event is fired, the execution finishes and enters the catch. The error is empty.

How can I fire the Application event inside the promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the then function in a callback wrapper:

```
.then($A.getCallback(function (response) {
    // ... code ... //
 }))
```

Or wrap the promise itself in a callback handler:

```
server: function({component, method, params}) {
    return new Promise(
        $A.getCallback(function(resolve, reject) {
            // server call //
        })
    );
  }
```

I also wrote a small [post](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2020/03/small-framework-for-server-side-calls.html) on a framework that I use that demonstrates a similar design, this loads in a static resource to call the server.

Here's a helper method instead:

```
server: function(component, actionName, params) {
    return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
        var action = component.get(actionName);
        params && action.setParams(params);
        action.setCallback(this, result => {
            switch (result.getState()) {
                case "DRAFT":
                case "SUCCESS":
                    resolve(result.getReturnValue());
                    break;
                default:
                    reject(result.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }));
},
```

Which is used like this:

```
    this.server(component, "c.getValue1")
    .then(result => (component.set("v.value1", result), this.server(component, "c.getValue2")))
    .then(result => (component.set("v.value2", result)))
    .catch(error => alert(error));
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I didn't know where to place the $A.getCallback function also I didn't understand if that could fix my issue. Can you explain to me why if we don't use the $A.getCallback firing the events break the code, please? Thanks again.

Comment: @ElkCor It's explained in [Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm). Basically, whenever you do something asynchronous, (setTimeout, etc), you can't interact with Aura. $A.getCallback puts you back within the Aura life cycle and allows you to fire events and modify component data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though I have already read that article I wasn't sure it will solve my use case, but your example was very clear. Is it something similar that we should be aware of when we use promises in LWC?

Comment: @ElkCor LWC does not have this probem, so you don't need to worry about wrapping the callout in any special manner.